# matlab - reading a table with different delimeter size

Tags: matlab

I have a table like this:

```
a    0.31  0.61  0.23  abc
abc  0.53  0.41  0.98  a
```

I tried reading the table using:

```
C = textscan(fileID,'%s%f%f%f%s','Delimiter',' ','MultipleDelimsAsOne',1);
```

It creates 5 columns where each column is a cell.
I need it to be a table(each column should have the length of the cell rows)

I also tried reading the file using:
`readtable('file')` but it gives me an error for different delimeter size

Comment: The first and last columns have to be a cell, since they contain strings of unequal size. Use [`table`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) if you insist on having a table, after having read it in using `textscan`.

Comment: But how do I convert the cells that I have in `C`(The variable after textscan) to be part of a table? Basicly I want to access the first row and first column like so: `C(1,1)` and not like `C{1, 1}{1, 1} `

Comment: You second assignment does not make sense, I guess it should be `C{1,1}(1,1)`. Tables are not meant to be used as variables, merely as a convenient container when writing stuff to file. As I said: your first and last column cannot become a matrix unless you pad with white space, I'd keep strings in cells always. The middle three columns you can of course just convert to a matrix using [`cell2mat`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html).

Comment: you can call cell2table to get a table from a cell array

Comment: `cell2mat(C(:,2:4))` works, but I do need the last column to be part of the table because at the end I need to randomize the rows(including the last column).

Comment: @MatthewGunn , `cell2table` creates a 1x1 table that contains the cell - it's not good for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
t = readtable('blah.txt','Format','%s%f%f%f%s','Delimiter',' ','MultipleDelimsAsOne',1);
```

Btw, readtable is basically a wrapper for textscan. If you don't want to read the first row as variable names, you can set that option to false with:

```
t = readtable('blah.txt','Format','%s%f%f%f%s','Delimiter',' ','MultipleDelimsAsOne',1,'ReadVariableNames',false);
```